# Frederick Douglas

Tags: meaning

What does this quote mean to the author (Frederick Douglas) ?

> By far the larger part of the slaves know as little of their ages as horses know of theirs, and it is the wish of most masters to keep their slaves thus ignorant

Comment: Slaves  are kept ignorant by their masters.

Comment: Which part are you not understanding?

Comment: @DJClayworth age as in how old or age as in current events?

Answer (score 1):

It means that, just as a horse does not know how many years old he is, the same is true of a slave (in the Old South), kept in an environment with no education, no records (that the slave can access), and very little in the way of a social order.

And this is the intent of the slave owners -- to give the slaves the absolute minimum in the way of a "life".